# Unable to call `setPageCount(int)`, on CarouselView

Tags: java, android, arrays

*error* in `setPageCount(int)` `setImageListener(anonymous ImageListener)`

i have declaration int array `mImages` but that no legible

---

its my variable declaration

```
public class CarouselView extends AppCompatActivity {
    CarouselView carouselView;
    int[] mImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.masjid_1, R.drawable.masjid_2, R.drawable.masjid_3
    };
private String[] mImagesTitle = new String[]{
            "Masjid1","Masjid2","Masjid3"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carousel);

        carouselView = (CarouselView) findViewById(R.id.carousel);
        carouselView.setPageCount(mImages.length);
        carouselView.setImageListener(new ImageListener(){
            @Override
            public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {
                imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            }
    });
```

my *error* in
`carouselView.setPageCount(mImages.length);` and 
`carouselView.setImageListener(new ImageListener(){`

cannot resolve method `setPageCount(int)`

Comment: What class is `setPageCount(int)` a part of? Can you show that code? And possible the AppCompatActivity class as well?

Comment: paste the complete code

Comment: Edit your question with your code, we can't read it like this.

Comment: Looking at this, there is no `setPageCount` method inside of `CarouselView`. The parent class also doesn't contain this method. You'll need to write it in order to call it.

Comment: okay, i will try it @Ausso

Comment: Did you really mean to do `CarouselView extends AppCompatActivity`? A View is not an Activity... You should at least  rename that to `CarouselActivity extends AppCompatActivity`